# Chef wrapper cookbooks only apply internal cookbook once

Tags: node.js, git, chef-infra

I have a cookbook "blah-deploy-nodejs-from-git" cookbook that installs a nodejs codebase from GIT and calls NPM install on the directory.  It has the following attributes

```
git_repo
branch
destination
```

I have then written cookbooks that wrap that cookook for inidividual sites, that need to get installed.  In this particar case "blah-pricing" and "blah-notifications" which have different overriding attributes:

```
me@me cat cookbooks/blah-svc-pricing/attributes/default.rb 
    node.override[:blah_deploy_nodejs_from_git][:destination]  = "/var/blah/pricing"
    node.override[:blah_deploy_nodejs_from_git][:branch]  = "master"
    node.override[:blah_deploy_nodejs_from_git][:git_repo]  = "https://hqdevgit01.blah.lan/micro-services/blah-pricing.git"

me@me:~/chef-repo$ cat cookbooks/blah-svc-notifications/attributes/default.rb 
    node.override[:blah_deploy_nodejs_from_git][:destination]  = "/var/blah/notifications"
    node.override[:blah_deploy_nodejs_from_git][:branch]  = "master"
    node.override[:blah_deploy_nodejs_from_git][:git_repo]  = "https://hqdevgit01.blah.lan/micro-services/blah-notifications.git"
```

And then the recipe is the same in both cases:

```
  include_recipe 'blah-deploy-nodejs-from-git'
```

Unfortunately it is applying the inner recipe only once even though my node has both cookbooks applied to it.  My understanding was that wrapper cookbooks are used to customize a cookbook and make it unique.

Can encapsulate the inner cookbook to two different cookbooks, with different attributes, and have the wrapper cookbooks both apply that inner recipe? OR Am I going to have to completely replicate the code that is in the inner cookbook?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to call this?  Is it in a role's runlist?  Are you calling them manually?

Comment: both the wrapper cookbooks are associated with roles, and both the roles are associated with a single node.

Comment: Have you validated that both roles are getting executed?  What you could try doing is putting both recipes in a single role's runlist and see if that can do what you need.  I've not done multiple roles on a single node, so I don't know if that's the problem instead of the shared cookbook.

Comment: Yes both roles are executing, but it is essentially crossing out the wrapped cookbook.

Comment: According to Chef's docs, "If the include_recipe method is used more than once to include a recipe, only the first inclusion is processed and any subsequent inclusions are ignored."  It seems like a bug that it's bleeding that rule over to different recipes, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a basic misunderstanding of how chef works.  Recipes are not meant to be a procedure for how to do something, they are meant to be a declaration of what that something should look like.  As such, you need to think of them as describing the end state, not the process for getting there.

Thus, chef will never run a recipe twice.  And attributes really should not be changed mid run (unless they are updated to indicate something that happens mid run.  Luckily, there are other chef capabilities that can solve your problem.  You need either a definition or an LWRP (light weight resource provider)

Definitions are just groups of resources that are often repeated.  So you can create a definition and then later call it multiple times in the same recipe with different attributes.  Much like what you currently are doing with your recipe.

While definitions are sometimes appropriate, LWRPs are generally more powerful, and have become the prefered approach for most repetitive (library like) task in Chef.  With LWRPs you will define a new chef primitive (much like file, service, etc), and then write the code for accomplishing the goal of that primitive.  You can then use these resources anywhere in your recipes.  In your case, you'd have an npm_deployer resource that took attributes for repo, branch, and destination.  It would then do the work that is currently in your deployer recipe.  Your "wrapper" recipes would then stop calling include_recipe and instead just declare a npm_deploy resource and pass in the attributes needed.

Comment: THank you. It tooka  bit for me to get back to this project, but ytour comments provided some useful insight